# Charsets and Databases

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

My boss likes to use n-dashes. They always cause problems with encoding and I cannot work out why.

I store my TEXT field in a database under the charset: `utf8_general_ci`.

I have the following tags under my `<head>` on my webpage:

`<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I pull the information from my database with the following set:
`mysql_set_charset('UTF8',$connection);`

(I know MYSQL is depreciated)

But when I get information from the database, I end up with this:
`Ã¢Â€Â“ Europe`

If I take this string and run it through `utf8_decode`, I get this:
`â�?�? Europe`

I even tried running it thorugh utf8_encode, and I got this:
`ÃÂ¢Ãâ¬Ãâ Europe`

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? I dont understand.  I even ran the string through `mb_detect_encoding` and It said the string was utf8.  So why is not printing correctly?

The solution (or not really a solution, because it ruins the rest of the website) is to remove the `mysql_set_encoding` line, and use `utf8_decode`.  Then it prints out fine.  BUT WHY!?

Comment: have you tried `htmlentities()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: You can set your tables to utf8_general_ci all you want, but if you store your values with (say) charset iso-8859-1, then you'll have your data stored in the database in iso-8859-1, and they won't be magically converted ever.

Comment: For what little it's worth, `utf8_general_ci` is ***not*** a character set—it's a collation, i.e. a sort order for the characters of some particular character set (utf8 in this case).

Comment: Also, for what even less it's worth, PHP's original MySQL extension is ***not*** depreciated (that's what accountants do to the value of assets, over time)—it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that computers handle all forms of data as nothing more than sequences of 1s and 0s.  In order to turn those 1s and 0s into something meaningful, the computer must somehow be *told* how those bits should be interpreted.

When it comes to a textual string, such information regarding its bits' interpretation is known as its *character encoding*.  For example, the bit sequence `111000101000000010010011`, which for brevity I will express in hexadecimal notation as `0xe28093`, is interpreted under the UTF-8 character encoding to be your boss's much-loved [U+2013 (EN-DASH)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013); however that same sequence of bits could mean absolutely anything under a different encoding: indeed, under the ISO-8859-1 encoding (for example), it represents a sequence of three characters: [U+00E2 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e2), [U+0080 (<control>)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080) and [U+0093 (SET TRANSMIT STATE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0093).

Unfortunately, in their infinite wisdom, PHP's developers decided *not* to keep track of the encoding under which your string variables are stored—that is left to you, the application developer.  Worse still, many PHP functions make arbitrary assumptions about the encoding of your variables, and they happily go ahead manipulating your bits without any thought of the consequences.

So, when you call `utf8_decode` on a string: it takes whatever bits you provide, works out what characters they happen to represent in UTF-8, and then returns to you those same characters encoded in ISO-8859-1.  It's entirely possible to come up with an input sequence that, when passed to this function, produces absolutely any given result; indeed, if you provide as input `0xc3a2c280c293` (which happens to be the UTF-8 encoding of the three characters mentioned above), it will produce a result of `0xe28093`—the UTF-8 encoding of an "en dash"!

Such *double encoding* (i.e. UTF-8 encoded, treated as ISO-8859-1 and transcoded to UTF-8) appears to be what you're retrieving from MySQL when you do not call `mysql_set_charset` (in such circumstances, MySQL transcodes results to whatever character set the client specifies upon connection—the standard drivers use `latin1` unless you override their default configuration).  In order for a result that MySQL transcodes to `latin1` to produce such double encoded UTF-8, the value that is actually stored in your column must have been *triple encoded* (i.e. UTF-8 encoded, treated as ISO-8859-1, transcoded to UTF-8, then treated as `latin1` again)!

You need to fix the data that is stored in your database:

1. Identify exactly how the incumbent data has actually been encoded.  Some values may well be triple-encoded as described above, but others (perhaps that predate particular changes to your application code; or that were inserted/updated from a different source) may be encoded in some other way.  I find `SELECT HEX(myColumn) FROM myTable WHERE ...` to be very useful for this purpose.
2. Correct the encodings of those values that are currently incorrect: e.g. `UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = BINARY CONVERT(myColumn USING latin1) WHERE ...`—if an entire column is misencoded, you can instead use `ALTER TABLE` to change it to a binary string type and then back to a character string of the correct encoding.  Beware of transformations that increase the encoded length, as the result might overflow your existing column size.

Comment: Wow, Thank you for such a detailed response.  And solution.  I've not seen the HEX() command before, or the binary convert, but i'll look in to them.  They sound like what I need! Thank you! +1